# PCAN_XCP using peak solution

Tags: embedded, can-bus, xcp

im trying to sart xcp communication using pcan-xcp but i cannot understand how i can use pcan-xcp API and pcan-xcp basic , i m so confused in the impementation and how i can test ,
the hardware that i had PCAN ,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgvo0.png)
i juste compile the c++ code , in samples folder , and this is the output .
what is the next step for peak , the offcial article is not enough to start

BEST REGARDS .